# Convert string of format "19-07-2018 08:10:24" in date and time both different string format

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, date, format

I want to Convert string of format  "19-07-2018 08:10:24" in date time format. If the date is today then it should be "02:12 am". If the date is of yesterday then it should be like "Yesterday". Otherwise it should be in "DD/MM/yy" format. Currently I am having the time and date in string formate.

I want the final answer in string type. If the answer is "DD/MM/YY", then it should be in string format.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried so far please

Comment: There are many answers to convert string to date, please look at them. And for yesterday thing, you can find the number of dates between two dates, if its negative then the date was yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Calendar date functions:

```
func format(date: Date) -> String {
  let calendar = Calendar.current
  if calendar.isDateInToday(date) {
    // process your "Today" format
    return ...
  }
  if calendar.isDateInYesterday(date) {
    // process your "Yesterday" format
    return ...
  }
  if calendar.isDateInTomorrow(date) {
    // process your "Tomorrow" format
    return ...
  }
  // process your "full date/time format"
  return ...
}
```

You can read more about the Calendar functions here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar

Comment: Thanks for the answer... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"//19-07-2018 08:10:24
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "15-07-2018 08:10:24")

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let startDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)

    let dateToday = (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: Date(), options: [])! as Date
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let strdateToday = dateFormatter.string(from: dateToday1)

    let dateYesterday = (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date(), options: [])! as Date
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let strdateYesterday = dateFormatter.string(from: dateYesterday1)

    if(startDate == strdateToday)
    {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        let startDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
        print(startDate)
    }
    else if(startDate == strdateYesterday)
    {
         print("Yesterday")
    }
    else
    {
        print(startDate)
    }
```