# How to display Yesterday, Today, and Tomorrow with DateFormatter

Tags: swiftui, dateformatter

Currently, I have been trying different ways of achieving this feat.
The way I have formatted it here produces the current date Aug 30, 6:28 PM

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestDate: View {
var time = Date()

var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "MMM d, h:mm a"
    return df
}


var body: some View {
    Text("\(time, formatter: dateFormatter)")
}
}
```

This is exactly how I want it. HOWEVER, I want yesterday, today, and tomorrow to appear instead of "Aug 30"/the relative current date. How does one go about doing this in SwiftUI

Edit: What I meant was when I use a DatePicker and update the date. Instead of "Aug 29, 6:50 PM" to appear I would like the string to be "Yesterday, 6:50 PM". All dates exceeding yesterday and tomorrow would show as "MMM d, h:mm a"

Comment: My guess would be to modify the time variable, perhaps by substracting a day, or adding one, respectively. Look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date) for instance

Comment: I added an edit to clarify my intentions. My apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `doesRelativeDateFormatting` (and don't forget to add styles), for eg:

```
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "MMM d, h:mm a"

    df.dateStyle = .medium
    df.timeStyle = .short
    df.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true

    return df
}
```

Comment: when yesterday, today, tomorrow are exceeded the remaining format is MM dd, yyyy at h:mm a. How do I retain the MMM d, h:mm a format?

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of what @Asperi said. The way I accomplished this was I wrote a function to format the way I wanted to.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestDate: View {
var time = Date()




var body: some View {
    Text("\(format(date: time))")
}

//this is where the function is I'm sure this could be cleaned up but here it is in its long form.
func format(date: Date) -> String {
      let calendar = Calendar.current
  if calendar.isDateInToday(date){
          let df = DateFormatter()
          df.dateStyle = .short
          df.timeStyle = .short
          df.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
      return df.string(from: date)
      
      }
else if calendar.isDateInYesterday(date){
      let df = DateFormatter()
          df.dateStyle = .short
          df.timeStyle = .short
          df.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
      return df.string(from: date)
  }
  else if calendar.isDateInTomorrow(date){
      let df = DateFormatter()
          df.dateStyle = .short
          df.timeStyle = .short
          df.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
      return df.string(from: date)
      } else {
          let df = DateFormatter()
          df.dateFormat = "MMM d, h:mm a"
      return df.string(from: date)
  }
  
  }
```

[This is also something that helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441372/convert-string-of-format-19-07-2018-081024-in-date-and-time-both-different-s)